# Is it possible to REWRITE a URL without htaccess file?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to shorten a url without using htaccess file?
for example I have this url.

```
this/is/a/very/long/url.php
```

change to

```
short/url.php
```

I hope I can get good answer THX guys:)

Answer (score 3):

yes, mostly used in frameworks

an approach called using a front controller

ex: your front controller is index.php

your page links are generated as a fashion of .../index.php/nything/url.php

but the actual link is .../this/is/long/url.php

the front controller extract the page information the client requested and show the relevant page related to it

read more : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question, there are multiple options however the .htaccess file is probably your best bet.

[this SO post describes it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873902/apache-rewriting-without-mod-rewrite)

Handling the url rewriting serverside is key here since it will be much faster to execute and will not break your script when used on some URL's.

so www.yourdomain.com/test/4/twenty/long/url/could/be/shorter/

all the arguments after www.yourdomain.com, can be retrieved via various PHP methods, including reading up on PHP's [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) would be a good idea, as lots of variables are placed in that global array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in **Javascript** for rewriting current URL:

```
if (location.href.indexOf("this/is/a/very/long/url.php") > -1)
  location.assign(location.href.replace(/this\/is\/a\/very\/long\/(url\.php)/, "short/$1"));
```

Comment: `Syntax Error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: @anubhava, Hi I have a couple of questions to your answer. 1) What is the $1 for? 2)Where should I place this codes? To explain further, that this/is/a/very/long/url.php, is called using a form. It has values that passed down from the form. So I'm sorry I'm a little bit confused here. But thx for your answer

Comment: 1. `$1` is back reference for string `url.php` captured from matched regex. 2. This code can be placed in your Javascript block on page that has URL: `/this/is/a/very/long/url.php`

Comment: what he uses is regex, these are patterns that match a set of characters, the written regex here is not dynamic however. In regex there are capture groups, e.g. parentheses `()`, everything between each set is captured, the first set reassembles $1, the second set $2.. etc. So if you have a capture group and want to replace something, you could put it in a capture group, and extract it from there at a later point in time by using the $1 / $2 etc arguments.
However this is not really a viable solution since JS can be disabled

Comment: Doesn't this redirect a user? Can you give a working example with a real URL I can try?

Comment: @anubhava I tried your answer, correct me if I'm wrong, your codes will change the this/is/a/very/long/url.php to short/url.php after it the form called it right? but it seems not working on the generated PDF, it does not change the url. I'm using TCPDF, I'm generating PDF using forms for its value and displaying it to a PDF file created by a PHP files.

Comment: Yes this code will work after this long URL appears (after form submit). Other option is to rewrite URL in php code using header function.

Comment: $js = <<<EOD
if (location.href.indexOf("educontent/wp-content/plugins/wordwork/admin/templates/tcpdf/samp/flashcards.php") > -1){}
  location.assign(location.href.replace(educontent\/wp-content\/plugins\/wordwork\/admin\/templates\/samp\/(flashcards\.php)/, "short/$1"));
}
EOD;

$pdf->IncludeJS($js);
This is my codes, its not working, hmm any idea?

Comment: It is quite difficult to read code from comments, can you edit the question and provide the code there.

Answer (score 0):

`mod_rewrite` is part of Apache, so it needs to be configured in Apache config. `.htaccess` actually Apache "live" config "per directory".

In general the best way ( I think) to rewrite urls is to rewrite everything to one file, let's say `index.php` and then "redirect" to specific file basing on URL. You can read a lot about "URL routing" in PHP on the web.