# Pretty urls Apache

Tags: php, url

I have a site where URL looks like `www.abc.com/abc.php?id=10`, now i want to change these to pretty URL like `www.abc.com/abc/10`, is it possible without rewriting the code if yes then how can i do that and any possible way without htaccess .

Comment: use htaccess for redirection and rewrite the urls in new format

Comment: Hi @donald123. i forgot to mention in my question that i don't wanna use htaccess. is it still possible without that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can simply use rewrite url within htaccess file.

[URL Rewrite](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

And if you want to rewrite url without using htaccess then you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873902/apache-rewriting-without-mod-rewrite) post

Answer (score 0):

Create file `.htaccess` in your `public_html` or `www` and add the following code into file `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^abc/([^/]*)$ /abc.php?id=$1 [L]
```

After doing above process you can access you script by using `www.abc.com/abc/10`